# Jolt transformation to move few attributes to an array

Tags: json, jolt

Am trying to write specs to transform a json using Jolt transformation

Input:

```
{
    "video": "10506207",
    "id": "ef3ef821-92cb-441b-b218-c10e543398e3",
    "session": "a7a55e610a813c36",
    "time-in": 180,
    "event": "init"
}
```

Output

```
{
    "video": "10506207",
    "id": "ef3ef821-92cb-441b-b218-c10e543398e3",
    "session": "a7a55e610a813c36",
    "events":[
       "event": "init",
       "time-in": 180,
       "time-out": 120,  (= time-in - 60)
    ]
 }
```

Basically trying two things:
1. Move 'time-in' and 'event' attributes to 'events' array
2. Add 'time-out'  = time-in - 60

With 'default' operation I could add attributes but couldn't do mathematical operations. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Also, if its possible to calculate 'time-out' based on condition, like if(time-in>0) time-in - 60 else 0

Comment: If you're doing this within Apache NiFi (one of your other recent questions was about NiFi), you can do this via the [Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) with a [`ReplaceText`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/index.html) processor.

Answer (score 1):

The fancy "time-out = time-in -60" is not supported by Jolt.   But it can move the data around so that it matches the desired output format, minus the "time-out" calculation.

Spec

`[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "video": "video",
      "id": "id",
      "session": "session",
      "time-in": "events[0].time-in",
      "event": "events[0].event"
    }
  }
]`

Comment: Thanks Milo, that seem to work. For that small math expression part, I ended up writing custom processor since that work for me better and Nifi had made it very easy to write custom code.

Comment: what if there are multiple elements in the events array and I need to add this attribute in all the elements in the array?  Is there any expression available to add all the elements in the array?